# How do I push object elements from GraphQL into nested array in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql

I do currently map through GraphQL data like so:

```
  const plotDataArray = data.allWordpressWpPlots.edges.map(plot => (    

    {
      geometry: {
        type: plot.node.properties.geotype,
        coordinates: [
          [
            plot.node.coordinates[0].coord.split(",").reverse(),
            plot.node.coordinates[1].coord.split(",").reverse(),
            plot.node.coordinates[2].coord.split(",").reverse(),
            plot.node.coordinates[3].coord.split(",").reverse(),
            plot.node.coordinates[4].coord.split(",").reverse()
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ))
```

The GraphQL query I use looks like this:

```
query {
  allWordpressWpPlots {
    edges {
      node {
        coordinates {
          coord
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

..and the output from GraphiQL looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allWordpressWpPlots": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "coordinates": [
              {
                "coord": "56.064655444812,9.6949704566207"
              },
              {
                "coord": "56.064575958599,9.6994982706574"
              },
              {
                "coord": "56.06046088577,9.6994719476694 "
              },
              {
                "coord": "56.060440367157,9.6951515896261"
              },
              {
                "coord": "56.064655444812,9.6949704566207"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The map function do return an object in the correct format, but my problem is that the "coordinates" node from GrapQL comes in different lengths. I want to loop through the node using a foreach-loop based on the length of the array, but I get a syntax error when I try to javascript within the map function.

How can I build a "coordinates" array with X amount of object elements from GraphQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest `map` calls. Not quite sure why `coordinates` is an array inside another array, but keeping that as is:

```
const plotDataArray = data.allWordpressWpPlots.edges.map(plot => ({
  geometry: {
    type: plot.node.properties.geotype,
    coordinates: [
      plot.node.coordinates.map(coordinate => {
        return coordinate.coord.split(",").reverse()
      }),
    ]
  },
}))
```